# JPQL: Enum literal in SELECT NEW query

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, jpql

I have a descriptor class for a couple of domain classes. The descriptor class has a field 'type' which is an enum and indicates the type of the domain class. In some queries I want to return on or more descriptors and pass the type as constructor argument. So my idea was to pass it as a query parameter:

```
  String jpql = "SELECT NEW model.ModelDescriptor"
    + "(t.id, t.name, t.description, :modelType) ... ";
  TypedQuery<ModelDescriptor> query = em.createQuery(jpql, ModelDescriptor.class);
  query.setParameter("modelType", ModelType.forClass(clazz));
  List<ModelDescriptor> list = query.getResultList();
```

This does not work. No exception is thrown but the type is `null` in the results. Also it is not possible to pass the enum literal to the query:

```
  "SELECT NEW model.ModelDescriptor (f.id, f.name, f.description,   
    model.ModelType.FLOW) ... "
```

**edit**
I get the following stack trace:

```
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in 
  EntityManager: 
  Exception Description: Error compiling the query [SELECT model.ModelDescriptor(f.id,
  f.name, f.description, model.ModelType.FLOW) FROM Flow f WHERE flow.id = :flowId], 
  line 1, column 78: unknown identification variable [model]. The FROM clause of the
  query does not declare an identification variable [model].
  at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.
         createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1477)
  at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.
          createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1497)
```

I use EclipseLink as persistence framework.

Is there a way to pass an enum literal into an SELECT NEW expression?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No there is not, in general there is no way to reference to the fields in any class and it is also not possible to pass argument to the SELECT clause. Only valid arguments to the constructor expression are (from JPA 2.0 specification, page 174)

- single_valued_path_expression
- scalar_expression
- aggregate_expression
- identification_variable

Comment: Many thanks for the answer and the hint to the specification. But the specification also says that a scalar_expression can be an enum_primary (p. 154) and an enum_primary can be an enum_literal (p. 177). But if I use a literal I get an exception. I updated my question and added the stack trace.

Comment: Well found, confusing BNF. Anyway I would not expect it to work in constructor expression or in SELECT clause in general. Have to check more if they also spell it out clearly somewhere.