# Passing a parameter in a jpql query select

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, jpql

I have a jpql query instanciates a java object in select clause

```
public List<ChampEtatOT> getEtatOT(Date dateDebut, Date dateFin) {      
    Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT NEW ChampEtatOT( ot.numero, uo.denominationFr, ot.etat, ot.dateDebutReelle , ot.dateFinReelle, :dateParam1, :dateParam2, :dateParam3) FROM ordre ot  JOIN ot.unite uo")
            .setParameter("dateParam1", dateDebut, TemporalType.DATE)
            .setParameter("dateParam2", dateFin, TemporalType.DATE)
            .setParameter("dateParam3", new Date("2015-01-01"), TemporalType.DATE);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

I put 3 parameters, so i can pass it in the constructor
I get this error

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-6137] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryExceptionException Description: An Exception was thrown while executing a ReportQuery with a constructor expression: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: dz.elit.gmao.commun.reporting.classe.ChampEtatOT.<init>(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.util.Date, java.util.Date)Query: ReportQuery(referenceClass=TravOrdreTravail jpql="SELECT NEW dz.elit.gmao.commun.reporting.classe.ChampEtatOT( ot.numero, uo.denominationFr, ot.etat, ot.dateDebutReelle , ot.dateFinReelle, :dateParam1, :dateParam2, :dateParam3) FROM TravOrdreTravail ot  JOIN ot.uniteOrganisationnellle uo")
```

I think that it's not possible to put parameters in a select clause so does anyone have an idea, the constructor method is as follows:

```
public ChampEtatOT(String numero, String denominationFr, String etat, Date dateDebutReelle, Date dateFinReelle, Date dateParam1, Date dateParam2, Date dateParam3) {
    this.numero = numero;
    this.denominationFr = denominationFr;

    if (etat.equals("OUV")) {
        if (dateDebutReelle.before(dateParam1)) {
            etatEntreeSortie = "En instance debut du mois";
        } else {
            if (dateDebutReelle.before(dateParam2)) {
                etatEntreeSortie = "En instance fin du mois";
            } else {
                if (dateDebutReelle.after(dateParam1) && dateDebutReelle.before(dateParam2)) {
                    etatEntreeSortie = "Entree/Mois";
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's not possible to reference a parameter in the contructor.
in your case it throws a NoSuchMethodexeption : it means that, no method with the current signature in your `ChampEtatOT` class (5 parameters instead of 8 )

you can refer to this answer => [Passing a parameter in a jpql query select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503845/jpql-enum-literal-in-select-new-query?answertab=votes#tab-top)

So ,try to retrive all data then make a filter method to set all the `etatEntreeSortie` values inside the `ChampEtatOT` class of the ResultList

Comment: Which is in fact wrong, as the linked issue says if you look at the first comment. This is a BUG in the JPA provider.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, as you suggested bRIMOs Bor it's not possible to pass parameters in a SELECT clause, so i have retreived all the results in a List than filtered the results according to the three dates date1, date2, date3

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT NEW ChampEtatAteliers"
            + "( ot.numero, uo.denominationFr, ot.etat, ot.dateDebutReelle, ot.dateFinReelle) "
            + "FROM ordre ot  JOIN ot.unite uo");
    List<ChampEtatAteliers> champEtatAtelierses = query.getResultList();

    for (ChampEtatAteliers champEtatAtelierse : champEtatAtelierses) {

        if (champEtatAtelierse.getDateDebutReelle().compareTo(date1) >= 0 && champEtatAtelierse.getDateDebutReelle().compareTo(date2) <= 0) {
            champEtatAtelierList2.add(new ChampEtatAteliers(champEtatAtelierse.getNumero(), champEtatAtelierse.getDenominationFr(), "Entree/Mois"));
        }

        if (champEtatAtelierse.getEtat().equals("OUV")) {
            if (champEtatAtelierse.getDateDebutReelle().compareTo(date1) < 0) {
                champEtatAtelierse.setEtatEntreeSortie("En instance début du mois");
            } else {
                if (champEtatAtelierse.getDateDebutReelle().compareTo(date2) <= 0) {
                    champEtatAtelierse.setEtatEntreeSortie("En instance fin du mois");
                }
            }
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Which is in fact wrong, as the linked issue says if you look at the first comment. This is a BUG in the JPA provider. Your "answer" is simply a workaround to this bug

Comment: Did anyone ever create such a bug report?

Answer (score 0):

Clearly the `JPQL BNF` **does** permit passing parameters as constructor arguments.

```
constructor_expression ::= NEW constructor_name ( constructor_item {, constructor_item}* )
constructor_item ::= single_valued_path_expression | scalar_expression | aggregate_expression |
    identification_variable
scalar_expression ::= simple_arithmetic_expression | string_primary | enum_primary |
    datetime_primary | boolean_primary | case_expression | entity_type_expression
string_primary ::= state_field_path_expression | string_literal |
    input_parameter | functions_returning_strings | aggregate_expression | case_expression
```

i.e a *scalar_expression* can be a *string_primary*, which can be an *input_parameter*. So your JPA provider is not meeting the JPA spec and you should raise a bug on it.