# Using hibernate 5, How to use CriteriaBuilder.literal(boolean) in my select expression?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, boolean, criteria, literals

Here is how i build my Select using JPA criteria API

```
CriteriaQuery<MyDto> crit = builder.createQuery(MyDto.class).distinct(true);
Root<MyEntity> root = crit.from(MyEntity.class);

List<Expression<?>> listFields = new ArrayList<>();
listFields.add(root.get("intField"));
listFields.add(root.get("stringField"));
listFields.add(builder.<Boolean> selectCase().when(
        builder.isTrue(root.<Boolean> get("booleanField")), true).otherwise(false));
listFields.add(builder.literal(false));

Expression[] arraySelect = listFields.toArray(new Expression[listFields.size()]);
crit.multiselect(arraySelect);
```

And My obj has a constructor :

```
public MyDto(Long pIntAttr, String pStringAttr, boolean pBooleanAttr1, boolean pBooleanAttr2) {
    // Build my item
}
```

I was using hibernate 4 and had a nullpointer on the handler so after looking in the net, and seeing there was now a BooleanValueHandler in Hibernate 5, I upgraded.

now the error i get is :

> Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [mypackage.MyDto]. Expected arguments are: long, java.lang.String, boolean [select distinct new mypackage.MyDto(generatedAlias0.intField, generatedAlias0.stringField, case when generatedAlias1.booleanField = true then true else false end, false) from myEntityPackage.MyEntity as generatedAlias0]

If i replace the literal(false) by literal(0) and I change the type of pBooleanAttr2 to Integer in the constructor, it works fine.

If I keep the boolean but remove it from the constructor, it tells me i have 4 fields in my select and only 3 in the constructor.

So what am I missing ?

Of course my query is more complex than this.

EDIT : For now I used this workaround to get a literal(boolean) usable in my my select :

```
protected Expression<Boolean> getLiteralBoolean(final boolean pBoolean) {
    return builder.<Boolean> selectCase().when(builder.and(), pBoolean).otherwise(pBoolean);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it may be a variation of this bug in, at least, hibernate:

[JPQL: Enum literal in SELECT NEW query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503845/jpql-enum-literal-in-select-new-query)

Bug Reference: [QuerySyntaxException "Unable to locate appropriate constructor" using enum literal in SELECT NEW JPQL query](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9875).